# [map_server in Noetic]Map_server could not open testmap.yaml error has occured!

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote my question because I have looked at past ROSAnswers and could not find a solution.

Also, I have recently started learning ROS and would appreciate any pointers as to what I may be doing wrong.

**[I want to do]**

I want to use map_server to create a global cost map and reflect it in Rviz.

And finally, we would like to have a real robot running within the global cost map we have created.

**[I did]**

I gitclone navigation from the following site to Ubuntu 20.04.

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation

I am trying to get the "testmap.yaml" in "home/catkin_ws/src/navigation/map_server/test" to work.

So I ran the following code and got the following error.

```
$rosrun map_server map_server testmap.yaml
[ERROR] [1666166341.180193818]: Map_server could not open testmap.yaml.
```

I also thought maybe the address was not set up correctly so I ran the following code and got the following message.

```
$rosrun map_server test testmap.yaml
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named test below /home/usr/catkin_ws/src/navigation/map_server
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/usr/catkin_ws/src/navigation/map_server/test
```

The testmap.yaml is as follows. I have not changed anything since gitclone because I wanted to test run it.

```
image: testmap.png
resolution: 0.1
origin: [2.0, 3.0, 1.0]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
```

I expect the following message to appear.

```
[INFO][3698178.3892394] Laoding map from image "testmap.png"
[INFO][3698178.3892498] Read a XXX X XXX map @ 0.050m/cell
```

Please let me know if you have any solutions to these problems. Also, what do I have to do for the message I expect to get?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408177/%5Bmap_server-in-noetic%5Dmap_server-could-not-open-testmap.yaml-error-has-occured!!/) by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- your testmap.png file needs to be in the same directory as testmap.yaml
- if you use rosrun as a beginner, your current directory in the Terminal should be where the testmap.yaml file is located. (Later on, you can put the map in a ros package, but that takes more work to set up.)
- have you installed `ros-noetic-map-server` from apt? You should do so.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on 2022-10-19**:
testmap.png and testmap.yaml are in the same directory.

I moved the current directory of the terminal to the location where the testmap.yaml file is located and ran rosrun again using all three methods, but the same error occurred.

```
$ cd catkin_ws/src/navigation/map_server/test/

Method 1.
$ rosrun map_server map_server testmap.yaml
[ERROR] [1666234839.837396681]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...

Method 2.
$ rosrun map_server testmap.yaml
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named testmap.yaml below /home/usr/catkin_ws/src/navigation/map_server
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/usr/catkin_ws/src/navigation/map_server/test/testmap.yaml
```

**Comment by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on 2022-10-19**:
I continue.

```
Method 3.
$ rosrun testmap.yaml
Usage: rosrun [--prefix cmd] [--debug] PACKAGE EXECUTABLE [ARGS]
  rosrun will locate PACKAGE and try to find
  an executable named EXECUTABLE in the PACKAGE tree.
  If it finds it, it will run it with ARGS.
```

When I run `sudo apt-get ros-noetic-map-server` I get the following error

```
E: 不正な操作(It means Illegal operation in Japanese.) ros-noetic-map-server
```

**Comment by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on 2022-10-19**:
Sorry! I solved!!!

Thank you, Mike Scheutzow!!!!!!!!!!!

I forgot to activate `roscore.`
I solved the problem by starting `roscore`, going to the location where the yaml file is located, and running `rosrun map_server map_server testmap.yaml`.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-10-20**:
The correct command is:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-map-server
```

**Comment by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on 2022-10-21**:
Thank you, Mike Scheutzow!
I made a mistake.
Thank you for correction.